# Better explanations of TAS Vs. TTAS in the context of "The Art Of Multiprocessor Programming" Herlihy & Shavits

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

So for some reason I am having trouble grasping the complete concept on why the Test and Test and Set function would work faster then the Test and set function from the book named in the title. Let me elaborate.......

In the above referenced book in the appendix it goes into the computer architecture a very little bit. I have a fairly good grasp of this already. It goes on to summarize that the TTAS is faster than the TAS function because of caching. I don't see how or why this is. Won't the TTAS function cache similarly to the TAS function. What part of the TAS function is causing it to work longer or what causes the TTAS function to work shorter.

Answer (score 12):

Each thread has it's own cache. Cache is updated only when the variable is marked as dirty. TAS (at the OS level) marks the variable as dirty whenever it's called, regardless of whether it succeeded in setting the value or not. This is what causes the big overhead.

Because of that, all threads keep invalidating the cache all the time. In TTAS case, you avoid calling TAS as much and therefore only invalidate cache on, now much rarer, TAS calls and when you release the lock.

Keep in mind that this is what we were taught and that I don't have a reference for you so you might want to look it up some more.